# Compensation for a cancelled flight AND loss of connection

Tags: cancellations, connecting-flights, missed-flights, vueling

I am trying to find out the amount of the compensation we have the right for. This is mainly due to the fact that googling for flight cancellation and loss of connection is unclear to whether it means loss of connection due to the cancellation or loss of connection And cancellation. This was a trip from Reykjavik (Keflavik Airport)  to Bilbao, traveling first from Reykjavik to Barcelona and then from Barcelona to Bilbao.

The flight from Reykjavik to Barcelona was cancelled, it was the last in the day so we were reallocated in the next one, which was the next day. Now, we also lost the connecting flight from Barcelona to Bilbao the next day due to a delay in the flight (the second one) and thus lost another day in Barcelona. Since it was, again, the last of the day, we were reallocated to the first one the next day, therefore losing two days.

Both flights were booked using Vueling and operated by them, same ticket. And it was a delay of more than 24 hours.

Please note that I have already made the claim, but I want to make sure they refund me what I am entitled for.

Comment: Are both flight on the same ticket, or separate booking? In the second case, you have no compensation for your second flight, it is compared as you arrived at airport late due to traffic (or car problem).

Comment: Both are the same ticket, both with Vueling.

Comment: So the only thing that matter is the expected and real arrival on final destination (so it is like a delay of two days). Check: https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/faq/index_en.htm (6th question)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi As far as I understand, that refers to lost of connection due to delay, but on the first flight. We of course lost the first connection, but also the second one.

Comment: Yes. the rules are not so well written for connecting flight. But the idea is that they are seen as one virtual flight. See it as "delayed". (to next day). There is no difference between cancellation and delay on claim and conditions.

Comment: Literally, there is no explicit compensation for delays (if you check on the directive), but the reality (and in EU passenger right site, and also airline sites) they introduce "delays". So your case is also more simple, it is cancellation and arriving more than 3 hour later.

Comment: Were both flights actually booked as connecting flights? I find it strange that for short-haul flights like these you would have the second flight on different day. Were you not planning to stay overnight in Barcelona initially?

Comment: Yes they were booked as connecting flights as the same ticket. It was the last flight of the day. There wasn't another one until 9 am of the next day.

Comment: Then no doubt that you are entitled to compensation on the basis of the delayed arrival at your final destination, provided it was not one of the exclusions (ATC strike, extremely bad weather...).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should have two types of compensation.

- two night at hotel, all meals, free internet and possibly refreshment
- 200 to 600 Euro (depending of the distance) because of arrival later then 3 hours as expected.

Unfortunately there is no compensation for the two days you have lost (and ev. prepaid hotel in Bilbao).

Usually airlines will deny you compensation, it is normal. They will take some excuses about "external events". Do not buy it. Document your delay, write down the timeline and what they told you and on PA (before you forget), and try to get some data on FlightRadar24 or on other sites, which you can prove that they are lying (weather, but it was just your flight, etc.).  Be prepared to escalate to national authority. It will be easy and guarantee success (if you claim has value).

Comment: We were accommodated in a hotel both nights free of charge and given meals. Do we also have the right for the 650 Euros?

Comment: Yes, these are two types and independent compensations: you are entitled to receive both. The first is also simpler: it should be provided in any case, the second is nor due to exceptional circumstances (and delays in aviation are usually not so exceptional, so most are real)

Comment: +1 This answer is correct. I received similar compensation

Comment: Why €650?  Doesn't a flight from Rekjavik to Bilbao fall under point (b), for which the compensation amount is €400?  I assume that you have some reason for also counting compensation of €250 under point (a), but that is not obvious to me.  Can you explain?

Comment: I have received the transfer, it was on fact 400 euro.